# How to play my audio file in jplayer audio player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, jplayer

I am trying to set up a Jplayer audio player. I have almost completed it but I want to know how to play my selected audio file from using $GET method and retrieving from database?

Here is link to audio player page which is suppose to play a file known as `Kalimba.mp3` which the file is stored in the directory `AudioFiles/Kalimba.mp3`.

[Audio Play page](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previewaudio.php?filename=Kalimba.mp3)

Below is link to jplayer instructions (commented line where error is)

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/

Below is the code I currently have, I commented line number where error is:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Preview Audio</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="jquery/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
            mp4: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp4",
            ogg: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
            mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3",
            wav: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.wav"
          });
        },
        swfPath: "/jquery",
        supplied: "mp4, ogg, mp3, wav"  // ERROR SHOWN HERE
      });
    }); 
    </script>  
</head>

<body>

<?php

$getaudio = 'AudioFiles/' . $_GET['filename'];

$audioquery = "SELECT AudioFile FROM Audio WHERE (AudioFile = ?)";

        if (!$audiostmt = $mysqli->prepare($audioquery)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}


// Bind parameter for statement
$audiostmt->bind_param("s", $getaudio);

// Execute the statement
$audiostmt->execute();

            if ($audiostmt->errno) 
            {
                // Handle query error here
            }

$audiostmt->bind_result($dbAudioFile); 

$audiostmt->fetch(); 

$audiostmt->close(); 

?>

  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: [Where did you expect this link to go to?](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js) It seems important.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The url should be `http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js`. This is strange because I have uploaded it into correct directory, why is url incorrect? Oh wait a minute, I see a slash in front of the `src`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ok the skin looks fine now. Now the issue is how can I get it to play my audio file?

Comment: It's because those URLs are incorrect. (Try for example http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp4 : it goes to a 404 page.) You're supposed to replace the example URLs with the locations of your own files.

Comment: @Juhana Yes that is a default file from jplayer, I just want to know how do I suppose to include a file I have which could be any file type. Is it suppose to be replace those 4 lines with `file: "<?php echo $dbAudioFile; ?>"` or am I suppose to replace each line as `mp4: "<?php echo $dbAudioFile; ?>"`,`ogg: "<?php echo $dbAudioFile; ?>"` etc.

Comment: You're supposed to use the format specified in the manual.

Comment: @Juhana It is just that at bottom of homepage it says it can play .mp4, ogg, wav and mp3 but then when going through manual it states .m4v and .oga only

Comment: I don't see that mentioned anywhere. It specifically says that you must have at least either .mp3 or .m4a for sounds.

Comment: @Juhana At bottom of this page: http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: Yes, it says "mp3, mp4 (AAC/H.264), ogg (Vorbis/Theora), webm (Vorbis/VP8), wav". I meant I don't see ".m4v and .oga only" mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Juhana If you look at the start up page when you build the audio player: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-8-video/, look at the last code snippet, it only does the default audio files which are .m4v or .oga. My question is that am I implementing, mp3, and wav correctly in my code when adding extra file formats? Also am I ok to change to mp4 and ogg or shall i keep it to what it was which was mv4 and org?

Comment: @Juhana Im in a bit of a rush now because I need to get to sleep, can you display me an answer showing how and where I include my audio file from db? and tell me if I am adding extra audio file formats correctly in the code? Thanks

Comment: @Ohgodwhy have you seen the last comment I posted to you for this question? Want to know if I added the extra file formats quickly in code and how do I get my audio file from db to show? Please look at comment above

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to continue this discussion. You're looking at a page that talks about implementing a **video** player with .m4v and .ogv formats (which are both video formats). Perhaps you should read the correct documentation instead.

Comment: @user1881090 Give me a few minutes to go through the documentation and what not. Are we playing Audio or Video files, or both?

Comment: @user1881090 Okay. I took a look at the documentation and created a local project to walk through it. Here's where your problem lay: You're trying to instantiate the jPlayer object with values that return false, because they're not media objects. So none of them can pass as true, (if you follow the links you have, they're not videos). The error is thrown at the line indicated because a false was returned from *all** set Media objects. What you need to do is build the file location and format first, then pass those in to the setMedia paramter.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry I hd to go run an errand because I was rushing I accidentally displayed the wrong page. It is audio not video I am interested in. Sorry about that, it is because I kept getting asked bear questions by juhana even though all I was asking was where do I display my audio files and if I put the extra file formats correctly and if they are legitimate file formats. At least you get straight to the point :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy am I ok using formats mp4, mp3, ogg and wav or do I have to stick with m4a and oga? Lets get through this slowly but correctly. Can you show a quick sample of what you stated. I will then mark the answer and get on with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below should do the trick:

```
$getaudio = 'AudioFiles/' . $_GET['filename'];

$audioquery = "SELECT AudioFile FROM Audio WHERE (AudioFile = ?)";

        if (!$audiostmt = $mysqli->prepare($audioquery)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}


// Bind parameter for statement
$audiostmt->bind_param("s", $getaudio);

// Execute the statement
$audiostmt->execute();

            if ($audiostmt->errno) 
            {
                // Handle query error here
            }

$audiostmt->bind_result($dbAudioFile); 

$audiostmt->fetch(); 

$audiostmt->close(); 

$info = pathinfo($dbAudioFile);
```